# displaying database info in JS script

Tags: javascript, mysql

I'm running into a issue when trying to display info on my website through a js widget, i'm fairly new to js in general so i cant seem to figure out where the problem lies.

```
series: [
    var query = connection.query(sql, function(err, result){
      console.log(+ result.length)
    });
    , 0, 0],
```

here is where its going wrong.

when its saved and i refresh the

```
var query = connection.query(sql, function(err, result){
      console.log(+ result.length)
    });
```

is breaking everything and the rest of my JS widgets disappear untill i remove it.

at the top of my js file is where i call the db connect, no where near where im trying to call the result

```
  var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'testdistress',
    debug: false,
});

console.log("Connected to Mysql");
connection.connect();

var sql = "SELECT * FROM offers";
```

When i tested it in the node.js console everything worked fine..
it gave me back everything i needed.
where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your code for series is incorrect.

```
series: [
var query = connection.query(sql, function(err, result){
  console.log(+ result.length)
});
, 0, 0],
```

You can't declare variable inside an array declaration. Instead do this:

```
connection.query(sql, function(err, result){
// Here you can declare series like this or however else you like
  const series = [result.length, 0, 0]
});
```